# How do you instrument binaries for afl fuzzing?

Tags: fuzzing

I'm trying to fuzz with afl, and its telling me to instrument the binary or just run a dumb fuzzer. How do Instrument the binary?

Comment: The documentation for AFL says that you need to rebuild your executable with AFL's configured gcc `afl-gcc`: https://github.com/google/AFL/blob/master/README.md  - they also have options for Clang/llvm.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fuzz a binary you should re-compile it's source-code with either `afl-gcc` (for C-code) or `afl-g++` (for C++-code).

You can find more info [here](https://github.com/google/AFL/blob/master/README.md#3-instrumenting-programs-for-use-with-afl).